# Does anyone know this font? ASF Weekly Ad

Tags: font-identification

I was reading American Signature Furniture's ad when I came across this neat looking 1.

Does anyone know the name of this font?

[image]

or this

[image]

The closest I came was [Shortwave Gothic Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/redrooster/shortwave-gothic/bold/glyphs.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based off of that "r" and "1", I am fairly certain that is [Knockout](http://www.typography.com/fonts/knockout/overview/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks very like [Silvertone Woodtype](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/thometz/silvertone-woodtype/) by David Thometz. The tail of the lower-case t as well as the cut-out of 1 are indicative. This image is from MyFonts:

[image: Silvertone Woodtype]

A drawback of this identification is that Thomertz only designed this extra-condensed version.

MyFonts identify it as derived from a gothic face by Robert Hunter Middleton's Ludlow type foundry, possibly Square Gothic or Record Gothic.

Comment: @user3131975 You're very kind, but the other answer appears to cover the other variants used in the ad (and I've +1d it).